# on applying toBeA() method on expect().toBe() it gives an error that cann't read the property of undefined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am applying toBeA() method on expect() and it gives the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBeA' of undefined** how can I apply these methods by chaining.

**utils.test.js code**

```
const expect = require('expect');  
const utils = require('./utils');

it('should add two numbers',() => {
  var res = utils.add(44,11);
  expect(res).toBe(55).toBeA('number');  ----> here it gives the above error.

});
it('Object should be equal',() => {

  expect([1,2,5,7]).toInclude(5); ---> here it gives the error TypeError: expect(...).toInclude is not a function
});
```

**utils.js code**

```
module.exports.add = (a, b) => a + b ;
```

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Which version of `expect` are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version 23.4.0

Answer (score 2):

The `expect` package API has changed since [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) took ownership and they renamed some of the methods.
If you check the [code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/matchers.js) of the `expect` package you will find out the `toBeA` and `toInclude` methods are not available anymore.

You can change your implementation with these methods that are available in the v.23.4.0.

```
it('should add two numbers',() => {
  var res = utils.add(44,11);
  expect(typeof res).toBe('number');
  expect(res).toBe(55);
});

it('Object should be equal',() => {
  expect([1,2,5,7]).toContain(5);
});
```