# Expect assertion library method not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, assert

I'm using Mocha and Expect to test my node application. It seems the `toBeA` method is not working. Any help. Here are my code and the error I got.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBeA' of undefined

```js
const expect = require('expect');
const util = require('./util');

it('should add two numbers', () => {
  const result = util.add(2, 2);
  expect(result)
    .toBe(4)
    .toBeA('number');
});
```

Comment: Well, does `toBe` need `toBeA` chained to it? Seems invalid to me. If you check to make sure it’s 4 first, a check to make sure it’s a number is redundant at best.

Comment: I checked it's 4 and it passed

Comment: I found a much better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574253/on-applying-tobea-method-on-expect-tobe-it-gives-an-error-that-cannt-read?rq=1).